# God is not monitoring delayed_job and restart it based on memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the god configuration I have done.

```
  God.watch do |w|
    pid_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid"
    w.pid_file = pid_file
    pid = File.read(pid_file)
    w.log = "#{Rails.root}/log/god.log"
    w.name = "delayed_job"
    w.dir = Rails.root
    w.interval = 15.seconds
    w.start_grace = 10.seconds
    w.restart_grace = 10.seconds
    w.start = "RAILS_ENV=production ruby #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start"
    w.stop = "RAILS_ENV=production ruby #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job stop"
    w.restart = "RAILS_ENV=production ruby #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job restart"
    w.env = { 'RAILS_ENV' => "production" }
    w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

    w.start_if do |start|
      start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.interval = 60.seconds
        c.running = false
      end
    end

    # When to restart a running deamon?
    w.restart_if do |restart|
      restart.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 200.megabytes
        c.times = [2,5]
      end

      restart.condition(:cpu_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 90.percent
        c.times = 2
      end
    end
  end
```

It is entering into the **:cpu_usage** condition when the CPU load is high but does not do so when the memory load goes higher than 200 MB. Is there anything in the above script that is obviously wrong, but that I'm unable to spot?
Or is there something more that I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from God documentation

> The number of times the test needs to fail in order to trigger a restart is set with times. This can be either an integer or an array. An integer means it must fail that many times in a row while an array [x, y] means it must fail x times out of the last y tests.

The **:cpu_usage** conditions gets resolved first as its *times* value is 2, meaning that after 2 consecutive fails God will trigger this condition. While the **:memory_usage** is set to [2,5], meaning that it should fail 2 times in 5 checks.

Comment: Ya. But constantly, memory is higher than what we have given in the condition more than 5 times. Even we have reduced the times also, not working.

Comment: and during that same time cpu usage is below 90% ?

Comment: If you comment out the **:cpu_usage** condition, does the **:memory_usage** condition trigger?

Comment: Yes, I commented the **:cpu_usage** condition and tested still it is not working and this time I have given 2 as value to times. still, it is not triggering.